# How to sum data in last record in postgresql using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data collection like this.

```
build   failures
001     1
002     3
003     5
```

*failures* column means the failures existed that build.

Is there any way that in SQL to output the data as this (sum all failures before current build)?

```
build   failures
001     1
002     4
003     9
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use windowed `SUM`:

```
SELECT build, SUM(failures) OVER(ORDER BY build) AS failures
FROM your_tab
ORDER BY build;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, while @lad2025 is generally correct I would add that for running totals you usually don't want to explicitly specify the ordering.  Usually you will get better, more maintainable queries by using the built in window for current row instead.

```
SELECT build, failures, 
       sum(failures) OVER (ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as failures_to_date
  FROM your_tab
 ORDER BY build;
```

This gives you an ability to re-order your query while keeping the running total being based on whatever ordering you decide (I wouldn't be surprised if optimisations are possible too with this, meaning it might perform better).